# spring data elastic search not searching properly on fields

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to search on three fields of my Index : title, authorName and Description;

My search looks like :

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                                .withQuery(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(criteria)
                                .field("title")
                                .field("authorName")
                                .field("description")
                                .type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.BEST_FIELDS))
                                .withPageable(PageRequest.of(page, size))
                                .build();
            Page<Ebook> ebookList = ebookRepo.search(searchQuery);
```

I have these document indexed :

```
{
  "took" : 12,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "ebook",
        "_type" : "ebook",
        "_id" : "9",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 9,
          "size" : null,
          "numberOfPages" : 10,
          "companyId" : 656,
          "price" : 10.0,
          "title" : "Welcome to my life",
          "authorName" : "JB2",
          "description" : "Welcome to my life 3",
          "language" : "FR",
          "ebookPath" : null,
          "ebookDownloadUrl" : null,
          "rating" : {
            "ratingId" : 10,
            "average" : 5.0,
            "starsByUserId" : {
              "131" : 5
            },
            "stars" : {
              "5" : 1
            }
          },
          "coverPath" : null,
          "coverDownloadUrl" : null,
          "iconPath" : null,
          "iconDownloadUrl" : null,
          "category" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "Webtoon",
            "subCategoryList" : [ ]
          },
          "subCategory" : {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "Adventure"
          },
          "repositoryGeneratedId" : "1588336718863",
          "userReview" : [
            {
              "id" : 11,
              "comment" : "I dont like it. I give 5 stars",
              "commentDate" : 1588336718989,
              "appUserId" : 131,
              "stars" : 5
            }
          ],
          "status" : "INITIATED"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "ebook",
        "_type" : "ebook",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 5,
          "size" : null,
          "numberOfPages" : 10,
          "companyId" : 2,
          "price" : 10,
          "title" : "Welcome to my life",
          "authorName" : "kosted 3",
          "description" : "Ceci est une autre description 3",
          "language" : "FR",
          "ebookPath" : null,
          "ebookDownloadUrl" : null,
          "rating" : {
            "ratingId" : 6,
            "average" : 0.0,
            "starsByUserId" : { },
            "stars" : { }
          },
          "coverPath" : null,
          "coverDownloadUrl" : null,
          "iconPath" : null,
          "iconDownloadUrl" : null,
          "category" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "Webtoon"
          },
          "subCategory" : {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "Adventure"
          },
          "repositoryGeneratedId" : "1588372761403",
          "userReview" : [ ],
          "status" : "INITIATED"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "ebook",
        "_type" : "ebook",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 3,
          "size" : null,
          "numberOfPages" : 10,
          "companyId" : 2,
          "price" : 10,
          "title" : "Welcome to my life",
          "authorName" : "kosted 2",
          "description" : "Ceci est une autre description 2",
          "language" : "FR",
          "ebookPath" : null,
          "ebookDownloadUrl" : null,
          "rating" : {
            "ratingId" : 4,
            "average" : 0.0,
            "starsByUserId" : { },
            "stars" : { }
          },
          "coverPath" : null,
          "coverDownloadUrl" : null,
          "iconPath" : null,
          "iconDownloadUrl" : null,
          "category" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "Webtoon"
          },
          "subCategory" : {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "Adventure"
          },
          "repositoryGeneratedId" : "1588372758036",
          "userReview" : [ ],
          "status" : "INITIATED"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "ebook",
        "_type" : "ebook",
        "_id" : "6",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 6,
          "size" : null,
          "numberOfPages" : 10,
          "companyId" : 655,
          "price" : 10,
          "title" : "Welcome to my life",
          "authorName" : "JBB",
          "description" : "Welcome to my life 2",
          "language" : "FR",
          "ebookPath" : null,
          "ebookDownloadUrl" : null,
          "rating" : {
            "ratingId" : 7,
            "average" : 0.0,
            "starsByUserId" : { },
            "stars" : { }
          },
          "coverPath" : null,
          "coverDownloadUrl" : null,
          "iconPath" : null,
          "iconDownloadUrl" : null,
          "category" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "Webtoon",
            "subCategoryList" : [ ]
          },
          "subCategory" : {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "Adventure"
          },
          "repositoryGeneratedId" : "1588336718576",
          "userReview" : [ ],
          "status" : "INITIATED"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "ebook",
        "_type" : "ebook",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "size" : null,
          "numberOfPages" : 10,
          "companyId" : 2,
          "price" : 10,
          "title" : "Welcome to my life",
          "authorName" : "kosted",
          "description" : "Book about my life",
          "language" : "FR",
          "ebookPath" : null,
          "ebookDownloadUrl" : null,
          "rating" : {
            "ratingId" : 2,
            "average" : 0.0,
            "starsByUserId" : { },
            "stars" : { }
          },
          "coverPath" : null,
          "coverDownloadUrl" : null,
          "iconPath" : null,
          "iconDownloadUrl" : null,
          "category" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "Webtoon"
          },
          "subCategory" : {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "Adventure"
          },
          "repositoryGeneratedId" : "1588372748126",
          "userReview" : [ ],
          "status" : "INITIATED"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I search with the term "JB" or "jb" even "JB2", I have 0 result when there are Ebooks with authorName  JB2.

I use spring 2.2.4.RELEASE and spring data elastic search 3.2.4.RELEASE.
What did I do wrong in my code ? Any idea about how could I correct it ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which versions of Spring Data Elasticsearch do you use? What is the mappings in your index? Your query seems alright, and this works here with my test application.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I updated my question. I use spring data elasticsearch 3.2.4.RELEASE